# $F(x - az, y - bz) = 0$. Find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

> Show that the function $z = z(x, y)$ determined implicitly by the equation $F(x - az, y - bz) = 0$, in which $F$ is a differentiable function, satisfies the equation
>
> $$ a\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + b\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 1  $$

My idea: define $c = x - az$ and $d = y - bz$. Then we get $F(c, d)$. Apply the chain rule there. However, this leads to

$$ 0 = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial F}{\partial c}\frac{\partial c}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}  $$

And this leads to

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 0 $$

The same thing would happen to $ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} $.

So the given equation isn't satisfied by this and I had no other ideas. The hard part is finding these partial derivatives, after that it's just a matter of verifying the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\quad \begin{cases}
X=x-az &,& \frac{\partial X}{\partial x}=1-a \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} &,& \frac{\partial X}{\partial y}= -a\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\\
Y=y-bz &,& \frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}= -b\frac{\partial z} {\partial x} &,& \frac{\partial Y}{\partial y}= 1-b\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}
\end{cases}$

Differentiate $\quad F(X,Y)=0$ :
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}dx
+\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial y}dy
+\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}dx
+\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}dy
=0$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\left(1-a\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)dx
+\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\left(-a\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)dy
+\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\left(-b\frac{\partial z} {\partial x}\right)dx
+\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\left(1-b\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)dy=0$$
This implies :
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\left(1-a\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\left(-b\frac{\partial z} {\partial x}\right)=0 \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\left(-a\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\left(1-b\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\left(1-a\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)\left(1-b\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)=\left(-b\frac{\partial z} {\partial x}\right)\left(-a\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)$$
$$1-a\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-b\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0$$
$$a\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=1$$

ADDITION after your comment :

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial X}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\left(\frac{\partial Y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} =\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}\left(\frac{\partial X}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial X}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}\left(\frac{\partial Y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)$$

Then you get the same equations than above.

Comment: I was wondering if you would please tell me your thought process in solving this problem. I don't think I would solve this problem even if I stared at it for 10 hours. Or perhaps tell me what was wrong in my initial reasoning.

Comment: Your calculus of $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ is not correct. Some terms are missing. See the addition to my answer. With the notations $X=c$ and $Y=d$.

Comment: There is a confusion about $\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}$. To avoid confusion, write $c=c\left(w(x,y),z(x,y)\right)=x-az$. Then $$\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial c}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial c}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$ And finally simplify with $w(x,y)=x$ thus $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}=1$ which leads to the forgotten term.

Comment: In fact the trouble comes from using the symbol $\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}$ for two different things : the partial and the total derivative of $c$ with respect to $x$. May be this should be better to understand : $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial c}\frac{\text{d} c}{\text{d} x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial d}\frac{\text{d} d}{\text{d} x}$$ $$\frac{\text{d} c}{\text{d} x}=\frac{\partial c}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial c}{\partial z}\frac{\text{d} z}{\text{d} x}$$